# body not sending using map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

    String url ='https://dev.jobma.com:8090/v4/jobseeker/login';
    Map map = {
      "email":"hope@yopmail.com",
      "password":"123456"
    };
    print(map);
    HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    print(reply);
```

and response from server  showing this

{"error": 1, "data": {}, "message": "Please add mandatory fields: email, password"}

Comment: Please check the question guidelines to improve the chances of getting a quality answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you attempted the answers that were given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that without the "content-length" headers, that server isn't accepting the request properly. This will make your code work:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.badCertificateCallback =
  ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

String url = 'https://dev.jobma.com:8090/v4/jobseeker/login';
Map map = {
  "email": "hope@yopmail.com",
  "password": "123456"
};
print(map);

// Creating body here
List<int> body = utf8.encode(json.encode(map));

HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');

// Setting the content-length header here
request.headers.set('Content-Length', body.length.toString());

// Adding the body to the request
request.add(body);

HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
print(reply);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier if you can use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package available in dart pub.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

```
String url = 'https://dev.jobma.com:8090/v4/jobseeker/login';
Map map = {
  "email": "hope@yopmail.com",
  "password": "123456"
};

var response = await http.post(url, body: map);

print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```

Comment: The domain he is calling needs client.badCertificateCallback to be set, or the call will fail. Did you attempt it?